# Moving UIImageView Moves Entire View

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uikit

So I'm attempting to make some blocks (called obstacles) fall from the top of the screen. This works, but my code moves the entire view down as well...

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIImageView * obstacle;
IBOutlet UIImageView * block;
NSTimer * obstacleTimer;
NSTimer * obMoveTimer;
}
-(void)obTimer;
-(void)moveOb;
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)obTimer{
UIImageView *cloneImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:obstacle.image];
cloneImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, obstacle.frame.size.width,     obstacle.frame.size.height);
cloneImageView.alpha = obstacle.alpha;
cloneImageView.layer.opacity = obstacle.layer.opacity;
cloneImageView.clipsToBounds = obstacle.clipsToBounds;
cloneImageView.backgroundColor = obstacle.backgroundColor;
cloneImageView.tintColor = obstacle.tintColor;
cloneImageView.contentMode = obstacle.contentMode;
cloneImageView.highlighted = obstacle.highlighted;
cloneImageView.opaque = obstacle.opaque;
cloneImageView.userInteractionEnabled = obstacle.userInteractionEnabled;
cloneImageView.multipleTouchEnabled = obstacle.multipleTouchEnabled;
cloneImageView.autoresizesSubviews = obstacle.autoresizesSubviews;
cloneImageView.layer.zPosition = obstacle.layer.zPosition+1;
cloneImageView.tag = numOb + 1;
numOb++;
cloneImageView.hidden = NO;
[obstacle.superview addSubview:cloneImageView];
}
- (void)moveOb{
    for (int i = 0; i <= numOb; i++){
        UIImageView *viewToAnimate = (UIImageView *)[obstacle.superview viewWithTag:i];
        viewToAnimate.center = CGPointMake(viewToAnimate.center.x, viewToAnimate.center.y + 1);
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    obstacleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self         selector:@selector(obTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    obMoveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self     selector:@selector(moveOb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    obstacle.hidden = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

So the blue blocks are falling down and so is the whole view. Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: may be because of `obstacle.superview ` why are you using this?

Answer (score 0):

Those tags are likely to cause you a problem. By default, a `UIView` has a `tag` of 0. So when you called up `viewWithTag`, are you sure you're getting the `obstacle` you want?

I've used tags many a time, often for different things in the same view. typically for that I would `#define` a `TAG_START_` macro for that purpose, and space them out, sort of like

```
#define TAG_START_OBSTACLE 10000
```

And every time I would assign a tag, I would use

```
NSInteger tag = indexIWantToUse + TAG_START_OBSTACLE;
```

And to regain the index,

```
NSInteger index = tag - TAG_START_OBSTACLE;
```

Though I must say, because I don't see the definition for `obstacle` here, I would think there's a better way to get the container `UIView` than using `obstacle.superview`. Perhaps the `UIViewController`'s `view` property? A container within that, or some `IBOutlet` you can keep a pointer to?